# comment some line in php.ini with htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a host in shared server.
Can I comment

```
extension=pdo_sqlite.so
extension=sqlite.so
```

from php.ini with htaccess file?
If yes,How?
Can anybody help me please?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to comment them but you might be able to do something else. You can create a new custom `php.ini` and set the path to it from the `.htaccess` file.

Take a look at this [tutorial](http://websistent.com/using-custom-php-ini-files-on-shared-hosting/) or:

1) Create a new `php.ini` file inside your root directory.

2) Add the following line to the `.htaccess` file (change below path with the path where you created the new `php.ini` file)

```
SetEnv PHPRC /home/username/php.ini
<Files ~ "\.(ini)$">
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

3) Now you can edit the `php.ini` file as you wish. (you can copy paste your previous `php.ini` and simply comment out what you want)

Answer (score 2):

Comments in `.htaccess` file is `#`. So

```
#extension=pdo_sqlite.so
#extension=sqlite.so
```

Comments in `php.ini` file is `;`. So

```
;extension=pdo_sqlite.so
;extension=sqlite.so
```

`Can I comment` - depends on if you are using these extensions or not (be aware, that some other extensions may be using them, read documentation)